# Mongoengine Document as EmbeddedDocument

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a mongoengine.Document subclass User defined.

```
class User(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'users', 'allow_inheritance': False}
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    password = StringField(max_length=50)
    name = StringField(max_length=50, required
```

now i want to use it as standalone document with its own collection but i want also to use it as EmbeddedDocument as part of Game record:

```
class Game(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'games', 'allow_inheritance': False}
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    name = StringField()
    owner = EmbeddedField(User)
```

but there is a problem. Mongoengine allows to embed only EmbeddedDocument subclasses. Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
class User(Document, EmbeddedDocument):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using a [`ReferenceField`](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields)?

Otherwise, you're storing two disconnected, but logically identical, documents.

Comment: Yeah I know. It's planned behaviour.

Comment: A late resurrection for a simple question, I know, but this is the answer. +1. Never store your data in two separate places (unless the need is tremendous and you already understand all the implications). It is really easy to expand a reference field in application code, and it is almost as easy to miss some edge case, forget to update the other copy of your object, and end up with inconsistencies.

Comment: @dokkaebi I agree with You 100%. I was just working with some legacy code/database and had to interface it via mongoengine. Some of our services were hitting directly to database. I started major refactoring with interfacing Mongo with RESTfull API to manage schema in one place. The next step was to improve DB structure as You say, but we split process in some steps to have better testing/control over it. And the first step was to switch every dependant service to use RESTfull API, and then change DB schema transparently :)